Bluetooth Jetpack Compose Implementation
I am building an Android app for a prosthesis but ran into the issue of trying to add Bluetooth functionality where I send strings to so select the pose I want to achieve.

I want to initialize Bluetooth
connect to the HC-05 module using its MAC address
using the buttons in the pose select screen when pressed to send
strings over such as fist, pincer, and tri.

Here is what I have so far:
MainActivity.kt:
val modeslist = listOf(
    "Pose Selection",
    "Pulse Control"
)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SHandControlTheme { // Assuming you have your theme set up
                Nav()  // Call your main composable function
            }
        }
    }

    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter by lazy {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }
}

MainScreen.kt:
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController, modeslist: List<String>) {
    var showButtonList by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black),
    )  // Adjust the color if needed
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.background_image6),
        contentDescription = "Background Image",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), // Make the image fill the background
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop, // Adjust image scaling as needed
    )
//Beginning of Column
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 8.dp) // Adjust if needed
                .border(4.dp, Color.Transparent, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), // Set rounded corners
            color = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "SHAND CONTROL APP",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                fontSize = 25.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(all = 16.dp),
            )
        }
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.shand_default),
            contentDescription = "Hand Icon", // Important for accessibility
            modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp), // Adjust size as needed
        )

        Button(
            onClick = {
                showButtonList = !showButtonList
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(50.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Gray),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Mode Selection",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
            )
        }

        if (showButtonList) {
            LazyColumn(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
            ) {
                items(items = modeslist) { item ->
                    ColItem(name = item, navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ColItem(name: String, navController: NavController) {
    Column {
        ElevatedButton(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(name)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(50.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Gray),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = name,
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
            )
        }
    }
}

PoseSelectionScreen.kt:
@Composable
fun PoseSelectionScreen(navController: NavController) {
    var selectedPoseImage by remember { mutableStateOf(R.drawable.shand_default) }
    var helpButton by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black),
    )  // Adjust the color if needed
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.background_image6),
        contentDescription = "Background Image",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), // Make the image fill the background
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop, // Adjust image scaling as needed
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 8.dp) // Adjust if needed
                .border(4.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), // Set rounded corners
            color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "POSE SELECTION",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                fontSize = 25.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(all = 16.dp),
            )
        }

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = selectedPoseImage),
            contentDescription = "Selected Pose Image",
            modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
        )

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        ) {
            PoseButton(poseName = "Fist", poseImage = R.drawable.shand_grip) {
                selectedPoseImage = R.drawable.shand_grip
            }
            PoseButton(poseName = "Pincer", poseImage = R.drawable.shand_pincer) {
                selectedPoseImage = R.drawable.shand_pincer
            }
            PoseButton(poseName = "Tri", poseImage = R.drawable.shand_trigrip) {
                selectedPoseImage = R.drawable.shand_trigrip
            }
        }

        // 3. Back to Main Screen Button
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        ) {
            ElevatedButton(
                onClick = { navController.popBackStack() },
                modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Gray),
            ) {
                Text("Back to Main Screen")
            }

            Button(
                onClick = { helpButton = !helpButton },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Gray),
            ) {
                Text("Help?")
            }

            if (helpButton) {
                Text(
                    text = "Welcome to pose selection, during this mode you select the pose you want the SHAND to make then provide an EMG signal to activate the hand.",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = Color.White,
                )
                // Optional: Add a button or timer to hide the text later
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PoseButton(poseName: String, poseImage: Int, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    ElevatedButton(
        onClick = onClick,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Gray),
    ) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = poseImage),
                contentDescription = poseName,
                modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp),
            )
            Text(poseName)
        }
    }
}


check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A41hkHoYu4M

You need to be more specific about what you need help with. Dumping your app's entire code here and hoping that someone else will finish the app for you won't work. Please edit your question and remove all code that isn't strictly relevant for your current problem and desribe that problem in more detail.

@Leviathan and  I updated the question and removed the Nav code

@ChiragThummar I have checked it and followed it through but I feel it got so big and I do not understand anything do you have any better resource for beginners
